# Unable to predict using XGBoost

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I have a program that uses XGBoost to predict a binary classification. I have finished majority of the code, but the very end in which I would like to use user defined variables to predict that class, I am having issues with. Before sharing code, the variable 'clf' is the optimal classifier that I have selected after performing GridSearchCV:

```
def prob1(LIMIT_BAL, SEX, EDUCATION, MARRIAGE, AGE, PAY_0, PAY_2, PAY_3, PAY_4, PAY_5, PAY_6, BILL_AMT1, BILL_AMT2, BILL_AMT3,
 BILL_AMT4, BILL_AMT5, BILL_AMT6, PAY_AMT1, PAY_AMT2, PAY_AMT3, PAY_AMT4, PAY_AMT5, PAY_AMT6):
    #1) Store user entered information into a series, convert to dataframe, then transpose so that it is all in 1 row just like in training set.

    lst = [LIMIT_BAL, SEX, EDUCATION, MARRIAGE, AGE, PAY_0, PAY_2, PAY_3, PAY_4, PAY_5, PAY_6, BILL_AMT1, BILL_AMT2, BILL_AMT3,
 BILL_AMT4, BILL_AMT5, BILL_AMT6, PAY_AMT1, PAY_AMT2, PAY_AMT3, PAY_AMT4, PAY_AMT5, PAY_AMT6]

    ud_df = pd.Series(lst)
    ud_df = ud_df.to_frame()
    ud_df = ud_df.T
    #2) Perform the same normalization and factorization of the values as done when loading the data in above.
    c = [1,2,3] # index of categorical data columns
    r = list(range(0,23)) 
    r = [x for x in r if x not in c] # get list of all other columns
    df_cat = ud_df.iloc[:, [2,3,4]].copy()
    df_con = ud_df.iloc[:, r].copy()

    # factorize categorical data
    for c in df_cat:
         df_cat[c] = pd.factorize(df_cat[c])[0]

    # scale continuous data
    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df_con)
    df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns=df_con.columns)

    df_final = pd.concat([df_cat, df_scaled], axis=1)

    #reorder columns back to original order
    cols = df.columns
    df_final = df_final[cols]

    #Predict
    prediction = clf.predict(df_final)

    #Predict Probability
    probability_pred = clf.predict_probab(df_final)

    return(prediction, probability_pred)
```

So what is going on inside the definition, is that user is giving those variables, and the continuous is being normalized, and the categorical variables are being taken care of via factorization.

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
prob1(50000,1, 1, 1, 37,0,0,0,0,0,0,64400,57069,57608,19394,19619,20024,2500,1815,657,1000,1000,800)
```

Error Code: df_con = ud_df.iloc[:, r].copy()

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

Any help would be great!

Here is a sample of how a row will look without any wrangling:
   [50000,1,1,2,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,64400,57069,57608,19394,
    19619,20024,2500,1815,657,1000,1000,800]

Edit1: Fixed bounds in original code. Am getting this error highlighting the prob1(.....) columns:

```
KeyError: "Index(['ID', 'LIMIT_BAL', 'SEX', 'EDUCATION', 'MARRIAGE', 'AGE', 'PAY_0',\n       'PAY_2', 'PAY_3', 'PAY_4', 'PAY_5', 'PAY_6', 'BILL_AMT1', 'BILL_AMT2',\n       'BILL_AMT3', 'BILL_AMT4', 'BILL_AMT5', 'BILL_AMT6', 'PAY_AMT1',\n       'PAY_AMT2', 'PAY_AMT3', 'PAY_AMT4', 'PAY_AMT5', 'PAY_AMT6'],\n      dtype='object') not in index"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list variable has 23 elements.

- r = `list(range(0,24))` has 24 elements. `r = {0,1..23}`

and when you use `iloc` to find the element in `udf` based on index, since it only has 23 elements, u cannot find the element indexed 23, it's out of bound as the error code said.

Comment: Proper grammar is recommended to post an answer for this question.

Comment: Thanks to the guy who helped me with the grammar. First time answer on stack overflow, not so familiar with the editor, thanks!

Comment: @XiangLi Very stupid mistake on my end, thanks for catching it. I am faced with a new error that I included in the edit. Do you think you can take a look?

Comment: @rmahesh since the answer resolved your issue, kindly *accept* it; please do not "update" questions with new issues - open a new question instead!

Comment: @desertnaut Okay will post a new one.